# Ошибка SimpleAdapter

Tags: java, android-studio

Добрый день!
Я новичок, в первый раз пишу под Андроид.
Не могу разобраться с SimpleAdapter (simple_list_item_2). Помогите найти ошибку  в коде.

```
public class example extends ActionBarActivity {

ListView misha = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.misha);

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map;

// Досье на первого кота
map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Name", "Мурзик");
map.put("Tel", "495 501-3545");
myArrList.add(map);

// Досье на второго кота
map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Name", "Барсик");
map.put("Tel", "495 241-6845");
myArrList.add(map);

// Досье на третьего кота
map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Name", "Васька");
map.put("Tel", "495 431-5468");
myArrList.add(map);

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myArrList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
        new String[] {"Name", "Tel"},
        new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
misha.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите, какого рода ошибка возникает. Если вылетает приложение, добавьте в вопрос стектрейс.

Comment: И какая же ошибка?

Comment: @fori1ton перед каждым элементом (map.put) error:(20, 8) error: <identifier> expected

Answer (score 3):

Запишите в методе.

```
public example extends ActionBarActivity {
Map cats;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myArrList = new  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map;

public void createCat(){
    // Досье на первого кота
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Name", "Мурзик");
    map.put("Tel", "495 501-3545");
    myArrList.add(map);
    // Досье на второго кота
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Name", "Барсик");
    map.put("Tel", "495 241-6845");
    myArrList.add(map);
    // Досье на третьего кота
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Name", "Васька");
    map.put("Tel", "495 431-5468");
    myArrList.add(map);
    }
    }
```

Comment: В коде ошибки нет, но приложение вылетает :(

Comment: Покажите лог ошибки

Answer (score 0):

переименуйте второй и третий map  на map2 и map3 соответственно

Comment: Не очень понял Вас. Говорит, что ему не понятен "put". (cannot resolve symbol put)

Comment: невнимательно прочитал, сорри.

Comment: может там русская р (в порядке бреда :))